# WPF XAML globalization

Tags: wpf, xaml, globalization

I have a WPF Application developed for US and now I am planning to make it ready for the UK market. The problem that I face is that some of the UI Options(coded in XAML) in the US are not needed for the UK. So I need to hide them and show some other UI elements in its Place. Please note that I am also planning to make it ready for some other countries too.So what would be the best solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this link [Globalization for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650.aspx#design_intl_ui_with_xaml). Especially the section: "Building Localizable Applications". I hope it will help you to achieve the goal

Comment: I had a quick look at it.I dont think MSDN talks about showing or hiding ui elements specific to a country. They mainly focus on localizing/globalizing the text/string/image/color etc. isn't it?